# Extract Icon From An Executable - ExtractAssociatedIcon

Tags: c++, winapi, wxwidgets

I am trying to extract the icon from an executable which is associated with html files. On my system, html files are associated with Chrome.

My code is:

```
std::unique_ptr<wxFileType> c_type(wxTheMimeTypesManager->GetFileTypeFromExtension("html"));
if (c_type)
{
    wxIconLocation location;
    c_type->GetIcon(&location);


    WORD index = 0;
    HICON hicon = ExtractAssociatedIcon(wxGetInstance(), (LPWSTR)location.GetFileName().ToStdString().c_str(), &index);   



    wxIcon icon;
    bool res=icon.CreateFromHICON(WXHICON (hicon));

    wxBitmap bmp;
    bmp.CopyFromIcon(icon);

    if(bmp.IsOk())
        MenuItem->SetBitmap(bmp);

}
```

The icon will be associated with a menu item and when the menu pops up:

[image]

It is seen that rather than the Chrome icon, I am seeing a different one. I tried it with different file extensions (xlsx, docx, rtf...) and every time I am getting the same icon.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

By the way, I am using wxWidgets 3.1.3 on Windows 10.

Comment: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_string.html#acd4ba44e34428aa83cd9922d2933d060

Comment: @macroland, that function can fail and you are not checking its return value. Also - are you sure that the icon index is 0?

Comment: @Igor, `index` is passed as reference, so the initial value does not really matter, it is just for initialization. The function returns the index as 1. `hicon` returns a valid memory address and furthermore `res=icon.CreateFromHICON(WXHICON (hicon));` returns true.

Comment: You've already found the problem, but just notice that you could also use `wc_str()` directly, there is no real benefit in passing via `std::wstring` here.

Comment: @VZ, thanks! it works like that too and prevents an extra conversion to std::wstring

Comment: This code has a potential buffer overflow. The reason you had to typecast pszIconPath to a non-const is because ExtractAssociatedIcon fills that buffer with the path of the file containing the icon it actually used. In most cases, it's the same file you passed in, so no problem. But when it selects an icon from a different file whose pathname exceeds the original string, it will overflow.